# matlab normalized problem

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I have 84 sets of data, the 1st set of data was normalized by the code below...The normalize equation is (((N-min)*2)/(max-min))-1)...

```
%read 1st set of data
N = xlsread('output1.xls','data');    

%normalize the 27 columns
N = bsxfun(@minus,N,min(N,[],1));
N = bsxfun(@times,N,2./max(N,[],1));
N = N - 1;
xlswrite('output1.xls',N,'normdata');
```

Now, every dataset have 27 columns. From original data of 1st dataset, find out the max and min for each column..so, we have 27 max values and 27 min values for each column...then by using these 27 max values and 27 min values for each column, to normalize the 1st set data and 2nd to 84th dataset...

The code below from b3 answer, however, which is different result from the above code.

```
N = xlsread('output1.xls', 'data');
minN1 = min(N);
maxN1 = max(N);
N = bsxfun(@minus, N, minN1);
N = bsxfun(@times, N, 2./maxN1);
N = N - 1;
xlswrite('output1.xls',N,'normdata');
```

May i know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: The min and max of the 1st set of data, which mean that each column have each min and max, so that for the rest of the 83 datasets, use the same min and max of each column from 1st set data to normalize each column of the following datasets, am i right?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the first data set is in a file called *output1.xls* so I'm assuming all your input files are of the form *output#.xls*. Store the normalization parameters for the first file and then loop over the remaining files repeating the normalization calculation.

```
N = xlsread('output1.xls', 'data');
minN1 = min(N);
maxN1 = max(N);
N = normalize(N, minN1, maxN1);
xlswrite('output1.xls', N, 'normdata');
for ii = 2:84
    filename = sprintf('output%u.xls', ii);
    N = xlsread(filename, 'data');
    N = normalize(N, minN1, maxN1);
    xlswrite(filename, N, 'normdata');
end

function N = normalize(N, minN1, maxN1)
    N = bsxfun(@times, N 2./(maxN1-minN1));
    N = N - 1;
end
```

Comment: maybe you should also pass the min/max as arguments: `N = normalize(N, minN1, maxN1);` to make the function less dependent

Comment: i have problem with the line minN1 = min(N)...however, minN1=min(N) is to find the minimum of the whole matrix..however, what i request is to use the maximum and minimum of each column from 1st dataset and then normalize the rest of the 83 dataset with the max and min of each column from the 1st data...may i know how to do it?

Comment: @noob - Have a look at the documentation for [MIN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/min.html). It will compute the minimum of each column by default.

Comment: the code you wrote get different result from the code i wrote in the begining. May i know how to improve your code to get same result with mine? The data of minN1 and maxN1 from 1st data are correct..however, after proceed the code you wrote, the result is different..why?

Comment: @noob: its because in your version, you are changing the matrix `N` (subtracting the minimum), then you compute the MAX of the changed matrix and divide by that. In the code above, @b3 computes the MIN/MAX before making any changes to `N`... Do you see the difference?

Comment: i see...the code i wrote is the normalize equation i need...so how should i convert the b3 code into the normalize equation i need?

Comment: @noob: according to your description, you want to normalize files 2 to 83 using the min/max of file 1. If that is the case, then b3's version is the correct implementation..

Comment: oh..sorry for misinterpret the question...1stly, find out the max and min from the 1st dataset, then by using the max and min to normalize the 1st dataset to the rest of 83 dataset...

Comment: @Amro - Good eyes, I completely missed the effect of the updated N array on the computation of MAX. Thought I was reproducing the same calculation.

Comment: yes..i manage to get the same result...@b3, the function part, N = bsxfun(@times, N 2./(maxN1); change to N = bsxfun(@times, N 2./(maxN1-minN1));..then both get the same result..hehe..thanks u guys...

Comment: @noob - I updated my answer to combine the two BSXFUN calls into one as you suggested.